# Circuit Analysis Sadiku Book practice problem 3.4 Nodal Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, nodal-analysis

[image]

In Sudiku's Fundamentals of Electric Circuits book, this is practice problem 3.4.

This is to be solved using Nodal Analysis.

I managed to get 2 equations:

$$v_1-25=v_2 \iff v_1-v_2=25$$
$$v_2+5i=v_3 \iff v_3-v_2=\frac{5}{2}v_1 \iff 5v_1+2v_2-2v_3=0$$
Having watched tutorials on youtube solving this specific problem, what they all do is take a supernode that encloses **both** voltage sources. My question is, If I didn't know this "trick" and I decided to take two different supernodes, how to arrive at the same answers? I tried using two different supernodes, yielded 4 equations in 4 unknowns but wrong answers (except v1).

Book solution: $$v_1=7.608V,\space\space v_2=-17.39V,\space\space v_3=1.6305V$$

**Attempt using 2 super nodes**

As mentioned we have:
$$v_1-v_2=25 \space\space\space\space (1)$$
$$5v_1+2v_2-2v_3=0 \space\space\space\space (2)$$

Combine v1 and v2 to form a supernode, and writing KCL at it (The convention used is current leaving the nodes is positive and that entering is negative):

$$\frac{1}{6}(v_1-v_3)+\frac{1}{2}v_1+\frac{1}{4}v_2+i_x =0 $$
$$\iff \frac{2}{3}v_1+\frac{1}{4}v_2-\frac{1}{6}v_3+i_x=0 \space\space (3)$$
Where ix is the current flowing from v2 to v3.

Now combining v2 and v3 into another supernode:

$$\frac{1}{4}v_2+\frac{1}{3}v_3+\frac{1}{6}(v_3-v_1)+i_y=0$$
$$\iff -\frac{1}{6}v_1+\frac{1}{4}v_2+\frac{1}{2}v_3+i_y=0 \space\space (4)$$

Where iy is the current flowing from v2 to v1.

So we have 4 equations in 5 unknowns. Here I tried to relate i_x and i_y using KCL at node 2 (where v2 is):
$$i_x+i_y+\frac{1}{4}v_2=0 \implies i_y=-\frac{1}{4}v_2-i_x$$

Substituted this into (4) to get:

$$-\frac{1}{6}v_1+\frac{1}{2}v_3-i_x=0 \space\space\space (5)$$

So (1),(2),(3), (5) are 4 equations in 4 unknowns.

Actually as I am writing this, solving this on wolframalpha, yielded the correct answer. I made a mistake in calculating the determinants using cramer rule, and so wrong answers. I apologizes for the question.

Comment: Do you *want* to use supernodes? Or, without knowing the trick, would you prefer to avoid them entirely? (There's no necessary need for them. But that doesn't mean it isn't good to know how to use them, too.)

Comment: No, I am okay with using supernodes, but this is the first time I see a supernode containing 2 voltage sources. (I was used to forming a supernode having 1 voltage source only). Thus, my question was, is it solvable using supernodes that contain only 1 voltage source? As having done that, I arrived at a wrong answer, and someone said before "there is double calculation" which I do not understand either.

Comment: What two supernodes do you feel like using? I'm not sure I see where you are headed. Do you just want to tie v1 and v2 into one such? What's the other?

Comment: v1 and v2 is one supernode; the other is v2 and v3

Comment: So, I guess I don't understand how you set things up (yes, I can read a few things up there but that doesn't mean I follow entirely) and how you got messed up results. Can you show me your *desired* process from start to finish? Maybe if I see that, I can point out where a mistake was made.

Comment: Sure, I will edit the main post to include my complete attempt.

Comment: I'm guessing that they way they handled the combined supernode was to just say that the \$6\:\Omega\$ resistor is irrelevant (it is of no importance, at all) and that all you had to do was to solve for v1 given:$$\frac{v_1}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{v_1-25\:\text{V}}{4\:\Omega}+\frac{v_1-25\:\text{V}+5\frac{v_1}{2\:\Omega}}{3\:\Omega}=0$$

Comment: Yes that is the way they did it. Sorry I actually solved the system of equations wrong and hence my answers were different, not due to using 2 supernodes. I apologizes and thanks @periblepsis

Comment: No problem. Glad to hear you've got a handle on it, now. :) You can, of course, do this entirely without supernodes [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZbYg.png). (rb=5 and just is the resistance being multiplied by 'i'.)

Comment: Oh this is really a nice method as well, to assume current source has a resistance and treat it as an unknown. I will try it to get used to different methods. Thanks very much!

Comment: Set up these equations: `Eq(v1/r1+v1/r4,0/r1+v3/r4+i1)`, `Eq(v2/r2+i1+i2,0/r2)`, `Eq(v3/r3+v3/r4,0/r3+v1/r4+i2)`, `Eq(v1,v2+va)`, & `Eq(v3,v2+rb*v1/r1)`. Then solve for v1, v2, v3, i1, and i2. Five equations, five unknowns. `solve([Eq(v1/r1+v1/r4,0/r1+v3/r4+i1),Eq(v2/r2+i1+i2,0/r2),Eq(v3/r3+v3/r4,0/r3+v1/r4+i2),Eq(v1,v2+va),Eq(v3,v2+rb*v1/r1)],[v1,v2,v3,i1,i2])[v1].subs({r1:2,r2:4,r3:3,r4:6,va:25,rb:5}).n()` gives `7.60869565217391` as a result. There are more equations. But I prefer this because I tend to make more typo or thinking mistakes with supernodes.

Comment: If you want, I can provide more detail in an answer to help with this approach.

Comment: Oh I see where the equations come from, though will probably take some time to get used to it! Will keep it in mind. The only disadvantage I see with this approach is when solving manually, it will have 5 equations in 5 unknowns; tough to solve without the help of a computer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I would consider using Cramer's rule if doing this by hand. But I also understand the desire for supernodes in the hand-case, too. But SymPy is so convenient these days I usually don't worry much about this anymore and I ***must prefer*** not making mistakes. So I avoid supernodes like the plague, now.

Comment: Ah got it. Will keep this method in mind when using equations engine solvers in general. Once again you helped me greatly, thanks!

Comment: Best wishes!!! Thanks for the kind discussion with me. I very much appreciate your thoughts and approach and only have the most profound wishes for you in the future. :) I think you will do very well and I'm privileged and honored by this interaction. Thanks!